# Using SQLAlchemy in AWS LAMBDA

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQL Alchemy in AWS Lambda function but it is throwing error:

> module not found.

Also I am attaching the folder structure which I am deploying to Lambda layer after zipping.

I am using the following command to create the folder for lambda layer.

```
pip3 install sqlalchemy --target Alchemy_layer/
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layer needs a different folder structure [according to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path).

Try this:

```sh
pip3 install sqlalchemy --target python/
zip -r sqlalchemy-layer.zip python/
```

Upload that ZIP as layer and try again.